# Polylang Is not working my other domain

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have install **Polylang** plugin in my wordpress website and i have link my domain at polylang for translate my website. But when i am going to my other domain, I have seen nothing. I haven't install wordpress to my other domain. Is that the reason for not working?

Answer (score -1):

Polylang is a WordPress plugin and it only supports WordPress. if you haven't installed WordPress on your other domain than it won't work.